# permission reporting on sudoers

Tags: permissions, sudo

I'm looking for a good, consistent and easy way to do a report of sudoers permissions for every user and group on the system. For users, I want the report to include permissions granted via group membership.

Comment: Do you mean `sudo -l`?

Comment: That'd be easy, but sorry... no. It's really reporting on systemwide sudoers for an enterprise environment. At least per system. sudo -l only works for the current user. I'm looking for something reporting for all users on the system and even resolving group permissions down to user level.

Comment: gawk -F':' '$3 >= 1000{print $1}' /etc/passwd | xargs -I usr sudo -l -U usr

Comment: frogstarr78: thanks, this is pretty good. But still missing resolving the groups.

Comment: but it at least lists the entitlements... make this an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

### Viewing user/group sudo access

You can either

```
$ sudo cat /etc/sudoers
```

or open with the intent of editing

```
$ sudo visudo
```

[Ubuntu Help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers)

---

### Logs of sudo commands

**/var/log/auth.log** contains information on when and which commands users execute with sudo privileges.

Start with:

```
sudo cat /var/log/auth.log
```

Comment: sorry, I don't want to report on what users were doing, but what they are entitled to sudo.

Comment: Oh, alright.  I have modified my answer to show you this.

Comment: Sorry, I know how to check the sudoers file. This is no reporting though.

Comment: So, are you asking for a seg/awk script to parse this file and return formatted information?

Comment: I was asking for a simple way to do a reporting on this. Check out frogstarr78's comment further above, which is close to what I've been looking for. Only thing missing there is resolving groups.If you take a look at sudoers files in enterprise environments, it's hard to keep track of user rights. So I've been wondering if there is a simple way of achieving reports on sudoers files without too much manual work.

Comment: I think that if you were to provide a 'sample output' of what you're expecting to see, it may be easier for people to help you write the script.  Either way, good luck :D

Comment: ;o) As stated before, check out frogstarr78's comment further above. This is already something that would do it. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Each time `sudo` is invoked who ran it and for what purpose is logged to a file. This file is different depending on your distribution and `/etc/sudoers` file. In SLES it is sometimes `/var/log/sudo` instead of `auth.log` since by default there is no `auth.log`

However, you said that you were looking for a consistent and easy way. I would recommend modifying the `/etc/sudoers` file to log to wherever would be best for you.

`logfile` is the option you would set. You can read about the options via `man sudoers`

By, default most distributions log via the `syslog` facility. However, if it does log to `messages` or `auth.log` you have to parse the information out among the rest of the log data. It is easier to use if it goes to it's own file.

Comment: Thanks, good explaination. But still, this is reporting on what users did, not what they are entitled to.