# user permission reporting based on extracted sudoers group & passwd files

Tags: permissions, sudo, access-control

Did anyone come up with an answer to this question ([permission reporting on sudoers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34821/permission-reporting-on-sudoers?newreg=8c5b1b5a696d41999bd7d7dfa50c6eca#))?

Comment: "Revival" of [permission reporting on sudoers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34821/permission-reporting-on-sudoers).

Comment: @Jim, since you seem to have the same problem as the other question, the right thing to do is to try those answers. If none of them work for you, I'd recommend editing this question to explain/demonstrate how they don't work for you, so that you can get proper answers. Otherwise, you can bookmark or follow that other Question to watch for future answers. Further down the line, when you have more reputation points, you could add a bounty to that post, looking for more/better answers.

Answer (score 0):

sudo -l tells you what you are granted. so you could run that on all servers and all user. Good luck with that ;-)

but I think you should ask why do I need to have such a report? We had a similar issue and when we combined multiple sudo files to just one the problem went away